# AWS tag should be alias to amazon-web-services

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are two tags: [aws](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) and [amazon-web-services](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services). I think [aws](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) should be synonym of [amazon-web-services](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) (similar as on [other sites](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-web-services/synonyms)). Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

> The following tags will be remapped:
>
> [aws](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) → [amazon-web-services](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) <sub><sup>x 5</sup></sub>